# How do I fetch the correct image id from specific row and send the individual emails?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to fetch the image id from the google spreadsheet but i can send the inline image either for 1st row or 2nd row.

I have added the "image id " in the google spreadsheet [ J column] and trying to fetch the id and send the inline images individually. There are different image id's on each row.

I have created the below code but it fetch the image id from 1st row only and send the email to all but i dont want like this.

how do i fetch the image id from the 2nd row and inline them to send mail to second row only.
if it is sending mail for the 3rd row then it has to fetch the image id from 3rd row only.

if the today's date is matching in the spreadsheet then it will sends the mail to that row only.

Sample code -

```
var last=ss.getLastRow();
var data=ss.getRange(2,1,last-1,10).getValues();
var data1=ss.getRange(2,1,last-1,10).getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i)
{
var row = data[i];
var d = new Date();
d = Utilities.formatDate(d, "GMT+0530", "yyyy-MM-dd")
var message = "" + d;
var textbody = message.replace("<br>", "\n");
var htmlBody = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('test').getContent();
var image = DriveApp.getFileById(row[9]).getBlob().setName('name');
var htmlEverything = htmlBody
```

Please help and let me know what mistakes I'm dong here ?

Spreadsheet image id screenshot -
![enter image description here][1]

Suppose I have the below rows in the spreadsheet.

ex -

```
ABC ----07/10/2020---ABC@yahoo.com-------(image id 1)
ZXY -----10/07/2020----ZXY@gmail.com------ (Image id 2)
XYZ -----07/10/2020---XYZ@mail.com---------(image id 3)
```

If I run this script then it is sending an email with (image id 1) to

```
ABC@yahoo.com & XYZ@mail.com.
```

here the issue is it is not sending mail to XYZ@mail.com with the correct id ( Image id 3) it is fetching (image id 1).

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `how do i fetch the image id from the 2nd row and inline them to send mail to second row only. if it is sending mail for the 3rd row then it has to fetch the image id from 3rd row only. if the today's date is matching in the spreadsheet then it will sends the mail to that row only.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and goal?

Comment: HI,I have a sheet which sends emails if the date is matching with the current date(today's date) and I have added the different image id's in each row.
ex - ABC ----07/10/2020---ABC@yahoo.com-------(image id 1)  ZXY -----10/07/2020----ZXY@gmail.com------ (Image id 2 )      XYZ -----07/10/2020---XYZ@mail.com---------(image id 3)
If I run this script then it is sending an email with (image id 1) to ABC@yahoo.com & XYZ@mail.com.here the issue is it is not sending mail to XYZ@mail.com with the correct id ( Image id 3) it is fetching (image id 1).
Hope you understand my question.

Comment: @RishikeshReddy I don't think there's anything wrong with your code. The issue seems made up or mistaken for some other issue. Check whether the issue actually exists. See [repro]

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `ABC ----07/10/2020---ABC@yahoo.com-------(image id 1) ZXY -----10/07/2020----ZXY@gmail.com------ (Image id 2 ) XYZ -----07/10/2020---XYZ@mail.com---------(image id 3)`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: HI, thank you for your reply. you can refer the above code and i have enclosed the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of your problem: you want to send an email with an image attachment to a set of users getting their information from different columns of a sheet if the date column corresponding to the user matches today's date.

For achieving this I have slightly modify your code to make it easier to understand (in terms of variable names) to other users with similar doubts. Moreover, I have used [GmailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app) to [send](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body) this email with attachments. To get the file, as it was stored in Drive, I have used [DriveApp's](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app) method [getFileById()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilebyidid).

The following piece of code will achieve what you are aiming for. I have added self-explanatory comments. I also have followed your same set up which I leave below.

```js
function myFunction() {
  // get sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  // get last row
  var last=ss.getLastRow();
  
  // get all the values from the columns A,B,C and D
  // .getValues() return a 2D array. Therefore, for iterating in a 
  // single for loop only once over all the values of our column, we 
  // need to flatten the 2D array into 1D array of the column values
  var colA = ss.getRange(2,1,last-1,1).getValues().flat();
  var colB = ss.getRange(2,2,last-1,1).getValues().flat();
  var colC = ss.getRange(2,3,last-1,1).getValues().flat();
  var colD = ss.getRange(2,4,last-1,1).getValues().flat();
  
  // iterate over all the rows with values
  for (var i = 0; i < colA.length; ++i){
    // set name, date, email and image ID to the adecuate values of each row
    var name = colA[i];
    var date = colB[i];
    var email = colC[i];
    var ImageID = colD[i];
    
    // get todays date
    var today = new Date();
    
    // set today and the date column value to the right date format we want them in
    today = Utilities.formatDate(today, "GMT+0530", "yyyy-MM-dd");
    date = Utilities.formatDate(date, "GMT+0530", "yyyy-MM-dd");
    
    // if the row value of date matches today, then send emails 
    if(today==date){
      // get the file using the image id
      var file = DriveApp.getFileById(ImageID);
      
      // send email with attachments using the file we just got and the information from each row
      GmailApp.sendEmail(email, 'Attachment example', 'Date : '+ date, {attachments: [file],name: name});
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: HI, thank you for your reply. i have updated my code. please let me know what mistakes i'm dong here.

Comment: You have several msitakes in your code. Firstly, in the second loop you are iterating again over ```data``` instead of doing it through ```row``` to access the sepcific rows. Change ```data``` for ```row``` in your second loop. Secondly, you are not using ```GmailApp.sendEmail()``` correctly. Please [check this documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options) or see my solution to learn how to use it accordingly. I has 3 parameters that must be passed and a fourth one for attachments. Check out its implementation.

Comment: Also, please consider taking a look at my answer as it has neater code and it explains step by step what is what and why I am doing what I am doing.

Comment: Thank you so much for you help, i have gone through your code and the issue is fixed now. thank you one again.